# Scala XML retrieving from optional paths

Tags: xml, scala

I'd like to process a document to retrieve a value that could have more than one path.  The ideal signature would look something like:

```
def value(doc: Elem, potential_paths: List[something]): String
```

Where it would simply process the doc looking at the head of the potential_paths, if found, return it, otherwise continue with potential_paths.drop(1).

With XPath, the "something" would be a simple list of String's representing XPath statements.  Since the "\" is actually a function of the NodeSeq, it's not (apparently) representable separate from a node.  Anyway, what's the scala-ish way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the paths are passed as `child/child/child`, then you could do this for basic search:

```
def search(doc: NodeSeq, path: String) =
  path.split('/').foldLeft(doc)(_ \ _)
```

Processing the whole thing could be done like this:

```
def value(doc: Elem, potential_paths: List[String]) =
  potential_paths.view.map(search(doc, _)).find(_.nonEmpty)
```

This assumes Scala 2.8. On Scala 2.7, replace `view` with `projection`, and `_.nonEmpty` with `!_.isEmpty`.

I used `/` as a separator here because it's the XPath character and avoids quoting problems. Note that there isn't a leading `/`, and that `<a><b/></a> \ "a"` won't find anything, as `a` isn't a child.